# Codekit + Sass and Auto Compiling

Tags: sass, codekit

I have `compass/sass` setup with my `app.scss` stylesheet importing a separate stylesheet for each of the media queries (as I am working on a responsive site at the moment).

I was wondering if there is a way to force the `app.scss` to recompile after I make a modification to one of the imported stylesheets?

At the moment I make a modification to one of the imported files, then need to re-save the `app.scss` to get `Codekit` to recompile and include the new imported file changes.

Not sure if this is how it should work in the first place and I have done something wrong...or if I need to add some sort of setting.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

**config.rb**

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
add_import_path "css"

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Comment: Codekit usually reads the `config.rb` file in your project's root directory and that's how it know which files to listen for change. Can you post the directory structure and the contents of `config.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next line
`add_import_path 'scss'`
to the config.rb

Or probably edit your first line with relative path to 'scss' folder.